# Reversing an MD5 Hash

Tags: security, md5, reverse-engineering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

I have passwords stored in a database using `md5`, and was wondering if there was a way to reverse the hash to email the user's password to him in case they forget it.

If that's not the most appropriate method, what is the appropriate method for dealing with a lost password?