# MD5 password decryption

Tags: php, javascript, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)
>   [Reversing an MD5 Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471654/reversing-an-md5-hash)

hi there is any way to decrypt md5 password field to allow user to edit password in form using javascript. or php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reversing an MD5 hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471654/reversing-an-md5-hash)

Comment: Please use [the search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=decrypt+md5+hash) as suggested in [Ask Advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) before asking superfluous duplicate questions.

Comment: It's one of the most important features of a cryptographic hash function such as md5 that you can't do this.

Answer (score 8):

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is one way hashing algorithm - not a means of encrypting. As such, there's no means of decrypting it - only checking to see if another source input has the same hash.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way, since hashing is not a reversible operation.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, but recovery of the origional string for hashes can be done with rainbowtables: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

(if the hash was salted, this will become troublesome ofcourse)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will recover A string that happens to hash to the same thing in the database. It doesn't mean it will be the same string that was used. If memory serves correctly, with md5 it is possible for multiple string to hash to the same value.

Comment: It is possible (collisions), but would that matter? Depending on your goal, if you have 'a' string, you can do your evilhack(tm) on whatever the hack will be on :)

Comment: well, it also said php, and the part in the question where it says "to edit password in form" has me baffled anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app a few years back that brute-forces MD5 hashes against wordlists and previously-cracked MD5 hashes it finds via search engines, see if it comes up with anything for you:

http://bigtrapeze.com/md5/