# Reset password and lock user

Tags: database, jsp, jstl

I have a user registration form , in this form  i am taking entry for name, email and password from user. I have buttons `save` and `reset password`.
save button save data in database. 
now in reset password button I have to reset the password and lock the user. How can I do it.
previously with this email and password user can entry in the system now after resetting password I have to lock this user. How, please suggest.

Comment: best way to lock the user from database fileds what @BalusC has told. and if youare looking how

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471654/reversing-an-md5-hash/13000731#13000731

Answer (score 1):

Add a column `active` to the DB which you set with a boolean or bit value, e.g. `0` or `1`. If the user has registered and activated the account, set it to `1`. If you want to lock the user, set it to `0`.

On every incoming request with a logged-in user, you just check the `active` column associated with the ID of the logged-in user. If it's `0`, then invalidate the session and redirect to the activation form.

Note: you normally use a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) or, in this case better, a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) for this, not JSP/JSTL.