# Revert urlhash into normal url

Tags: url, hash, drupal-7

I use the [Linkchecker](http://drupal.org/project/linkchecker) module on my website but the database stores my urls as a *urlhash*. I'm not familiar with this kind of security, so is there anyway I can revert these strings back to the original url?

Comment: can you post an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashing is a one-way process, designed to create signatures or fingerprints that are easily comparable by a machine. 
Reverting hashes to their original strings is almost impossible (depending on the hashing algorithm) and involves reverse engineering and number crunching.

So, to answer your question in short: no this is not possible.

see [a similar discussion on md5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471654/reversing-an-md5-hash)

Comment: Ah damn, thanks for the effort! I'll have to find an other way :)