# Reverse code. Guid to String in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reversing an MD5 Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471654/reversing-an-md5-hash)

I have a bit of code which I use to create a Guid from a String.

The code works fine but I now need to reverse the Guid it created and convert it back to the string.

Here is the code that I use to convert the String to Guid:

```
$s = strtoupper(md5($myString));
$guidText = 
substr($s,0,8) . '-' . 
substr($s,8,4) . '-' . 
substr($s,12,4). '-' . 
substr($s,16,4). '-' . 
substr($s,20); 

echo $guidText;
```

How can I reverse this code?

Comment: You cannot reverse a md5 hashed string.

Comment: http://www.golubev.com/hashgpu.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`md5()` is a a hash function. Hash functions are not reversable

Answer (score 3):

You can only reverse it back to MD5 hash. You can't really *reverse* MD5 hash back to it's original string.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `encryption/decryption` functions, not `hash function`(such as `md5`). Hash function are not reversable.