# MD5 to String Convert Logic

Tags: md5

I have seen there is some online site which can convert MD5 code online.
but i want to know the logic behind it.
How to convert md5 to string.
like I have:

0192023a7bbd73250516f069df18b500
convert it to String
there is some site which is converting to its original like
http://md5.gromweb.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reversing an MD5 Hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471654/reversing-an-md5-hash)

Comment: That already is a string.  So please clarify what result you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to "decrypt" md5 to it's original string, as it is a one way hashing algorithm.

Imagine you taking a small video maybe 100MB big, and making an MD5 hash out of it, how in the world would you get that back from a 32 Byte string? Or in your case maybe just a single german word like "*Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitänsmütze*" which in itself has 48 characters.

But this does NOT mean that it is safe to use, in fact quite the opposite is true.

- For easy passwords you might find a quick match using a **dictonary attack**
- There are loads of **rainbow tables** for MD5
- Most of all, there have been found algorithms to find a match (collision) for an MD5 encoded string, in realtively short time (-> without having to wait for the sun to die before that happens)

There are still valid cases to use MD5, but just understand the background and thereby know where not to use it. Eg for storing passwords you should consider using a **salted hash** algorithm.

(Bold words are good suggestions to google for more background info)

Comment: Sir, There is some online site that is converting MD5 to Original String

http://md5.gromweb.com/

Comment: That is a reverse lookup, or rainbow table, ... it does not convert it (even if it states it on that page), but rather looks it up in a table of pre-processed values.

Comment: Also on this site it states "This method appears to be safe as it seems impossible to retrieve original user passwords ... Unfortunately, there is a way to decrypt a MD5 hash, using a dictionary populated with strings and their MD5 counterpart.", right hand side under "Is it secure?" :-)

Comment: If this answers your question, consider also accepting it (green checkmark) ;-)