# Get the Next Element of the Next Column of Same Row in PDO/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Suppose I have a database table consisting of three columns - Userid, Username & Password. And let's assume I am building a Log-in Form and the password is stored in encrypted form. So, before it can be compared with the original password, it needs to be processed a little.

So, I let the user enter the username and password in the form.

```
include('db.php');      
$getuid = $connection->prepare('SELECT FROM users WHERE username = :u');
$getuid->execute(array("u" => $_REQUEST['username']));
```

Now, I have executed the statement, and the row with the Entered Username is selected.

**What I Want to Do ?**

After Selecting the Row, I want the corresponding Password(which is in encrypted form) and Userid to be stored in `$pass`, `$userid` variables.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `select` query needs to be `$getuid = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :u');` where `*` selects/gets all columns from the table users.

Then traverse the results, as per their column names (username, and say pwd) to get their corresponding values, as shown below:

```
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ( $results as $v) {
     $username = $v['username'];
     $pwd = $v['pwd']; 
     }
```

**Note:** you cannot retrieve the original or decoded password, its explained nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637891/how-to-decrypt-md5-hash)

Answer (score 0):

If user enters a username as uname,then use this query to get

```
select password,userid from users where user_name=uname
```

Comment: And, How to store the selected password and userid ?

Comment: in php i dnt have idea how to get that

Comment: also the above query you have mentioned is not correct "$getuid = $connection->prepare('SELECT FROM users WHERE username = :u');" here you have no columns or * in your select statement