# How to output MD5 hashed password in plain text?

Tags: php, md5

I have passwords for members on a site encrypted using MD5 and stored in the database. I want to implement a lost password functionality where the user will be emailed their credentials if they forget them. But how to output the unencrypted password or is it one way encryption and hence impossible?

Comment: @Slaks: No, he *should* use MD5. He *shouldn't* allow them to recover the plain text password.

Comment: This isn't the first time I've heard this question -- why are people even hashing passwords if they don't understand it's irreversible? There would be no benefit if you could get the plaintext back

Comment: @Josh K - @SLaks's point here is that MD5 is a weak algorithm, not that hashing itself is bad.

Comment: @Josh: No.  He should use bcrypt.

Comment: @Slaks: blowfish is a block cipher, not a hash.  There's a modified version that is a hash, but unclear how much collision analysis has been done (this isn't to say that MD5 is good - it isn't).  All that being said, you should always hash passwords, not encrypt them.

Comment: (@SLack, correct me if I'm wrong, but) I think SLak's point was that if this is the result the OP wants to achieve, MD5 is a bad choice since it's a hash algorithm, and not an encryption algorithm.

Comment: @Slaks: What do you gain (other then loss of security) by storing passwords in a reversible manner?

Comment: @Josh K: i.e. Many of strong, challenge-response based, authentication schemes require storing plaintext passwords.

Comment: @el.pescado: Like what? I can't think of *any* reason to store a plaintext password. Store the hash and compare the hashes.

Comment: Like, for example, CRAM-MD5 or authentication schemes used in Jabber.

Comment: It's funny that people are afraid to store plaintext password in database, which is reasonably secure place, but sending password in plaintext over network (which is inherently insecure) is perfectly OK for them. Note that many sites still don't use SSL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

Comment: He should not use MD5. Password hashes need to be expensive, and need a salt. So you should use a hash designed for hashing passwords, such as bcrypt, PBKDF2 or scrypt. You should not use a general purpose hash, such as MD5 or SHA-2. Encryption isn't the correct choice either.

Comment: @NickBastin bcrypt is a password hash, blowfish a cipher. While bcrypt reuses part of blowfish, it's still a different construction. Bcrypt is appropriate here, blowfish isn't.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

MD5 isn't encryption - it's a one-way hash.  You can't reverse a one-way hash (theoretically you can find a plaintext that has an equivalent hash which is generally as good, but you can't in any reasonable amount of time), so you just need to set a new password and email it to them as a temporary, and/or just provide them a link to reset their password.

Comment: Actually what you describe isn't reversing the hash.  The best you can do is find a plaintext that hashes to the same value.  Asserting that what you find is the same as the original (and not simply a hash collision) assumes more than you actually know.

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't actually matter - as soon as you can find plaintext that hashes to the same value, you can defeat it.

Comment: Well if the intention of attempting to reverse the hash is to retrieve the original text and not a different one that works then it does matter.

Comment: +1. "MD5 isn't encryption - it's a one-way hash." That explains everything.

Comment: As Slartibartfast said, you can't, even theoretically.

Comment: @Slartibardfast and @David 天宇 Wong, if the candidates are `password` and an infinite number of quite long, random-looking passwords then, theoretically speaking, the probability of the first one is beyond reasonable doubt. Practically, statistical tests are used to determine automatically whether regular cipher cracking has succeeded or not so that the results can be checked by a human.

Comment: In practice you can reverse it quite often, because typical passwords are easy to guess, and MD5 is fast (you can try several billion candidates per second on a GPU). That's why MD5 is not an appropriate password hash.

Answer (score 6):

The point of using a one-way hash is to *prevent* exactly what you are trying to do.  If you can read the plaintext password, then anyone who gets a hold of your database can too.  Hint: what do you do with old backup media? Throw them in the trash?  Criminals have been known to dumpster-dive for backups.

Instead of sending the user's password back to them, set up a system so they can reset their password.  Read up on some articles about this before implementing it.

Answer (score 3):

[Entire answer replaced thanks to prompting from CodesInChaos; the previous answer is in history.]

You should not use MD5 to store your passwords. See the [LinkedIn password breach](http://erratasec.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/linkedin-vs-password-cracking.html) if you need any more compelling reason to move away from MD5.

To prevent a password database breach from being the headline news that it was for LinkedIn, you need to use a significantly better hashing function. DES-based `crypt(3)` might have been good enough in the late 70s, but [modern bruteforce searching tools](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-plus/) can easily test millions of candidate passwords per second.

By contrast, that same tool is able to bruteforce just thousands of [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) hashes per second. (Sadly they do not publish [scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) timings.) Your MD5 is *millions* of times worse than either of these ready replacements.

For a larger look at password safety, I recommend reading the [Password security: past, present, future](http://openwall.com/presentations/Passwords12-The-Future-Of-Hashing/) slides.

Comment: I've never heard of that weakness in MD5 before... And I thought SHA-512 just made it harder by making attacks just take forever, not actually more secure. Hmmm.. I learned something today. +1

Comment: These collision attacks are irrelevant for password hashing. The relevant attack is guessing the correct password, which you limit by using a salt(prevents multi-target attacks) and a slow hash. Plain SHA-2 is almost as bad as plain MD5.

Answer (score 1):

## No

You can't recover the original password from the MD5 hash. It's a one way hash function.

### Also

You shouldn't be providing them with the plain text password. What you should do instead is either allow them to change the password, or generate a random one for them to use and then force them to change it.

Comment: Using rainbow tables, it's possible to recover original passwords to some degree.

Comment: @Jon: While you are technically "recovering" the plain text of the hash, he is asking if the hash is a type of reversible encryption which it is not.

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't use MD5. Use sha1 and use also a salt, there is a lot of information on the internet.
2. The purpose of hashing the password is exactly that. It is used because the original password can't be gotten (theorically) so the password would be saved securily and it can be used to check if the password is correct easily.
3. Allmost all websites chose to generate a new password and send it by email as the forget password mechanism.

Comment: Even SHA-1 is rapidly becoming deprecated for new deployments, in favour of the SHA-2 family.

Answer (score 1):

While it has been pointed ou that md5 is a hashing function, a function that takes a password and returns a string eg. `f(password) == hash`.

It IS possible to calculate a password that when put through this function that gives the same hash e.g `f(password) == hash == f(password")`

This is normally done by precaculating all of the possible passwords and storing the hashes of these in a rainbow table ([See Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)).  It is possible to download such rainbow tables but they are HUGE!

You may not recover the same password that the user originally used due to collisions in the hashing function.

Answer (score -1):

[md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) is a one-way <strike>encryption</strike>/hashing function.  Once hashed, a string can only be compared to it's hashed version and not decrypted.