# How can I decrypt passwords hashed using the MD5 algorithm from a Drupal database?

Tags: php, drupal, md5

My project requires list of all users with their password. Drupal stores these passwords after applying an MD5 hash. How can I get the original password for the user?

Comment: There is _never_ a reason to decrypt other users passwods! Additional the phrase "My project requires list of __all users with their password__" should make you _very_ skeptical

Comment: Wait, what? You want me to help you steal a bunch of usernames and passwords!?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126255/how-to-output-md5-hashed-password-in-plain-text

Related question...

Comment: kingCrunch and DOK,thanks for supporting user's privacy. But this project is not a social networking or any public website. In this project admin himself is registering users. So there might be chances of loosing user's password. So admin needs some download option where he can get all the user with their password.

Comment: D6 passwords are md5 and D7 are SHA with hash FYI. 
No matter Drupal or whatever, hashes cannot be decrypted unless you use some web service to get the matches using their web service. 

And "Decryption" doesn't make sense for md5. Tell "Unhash" instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MD5 is a one-way hash function. There's no non-trivial way to reverse it, which is why it (and other one-way hash functions) are used for storing passwords. However, you might be able to use [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to try to reverse the hash, but the effectiveness depends on the complexity of the password and the salt used (if one is used). Rainbow tables are also a very costly in terms of time and computational resources.

I would recommend reconsidering why you need the password. Generally, working with user passwords is a bad idea. There's probably an alternative solution out there.

Answer (score -3):

If they're already in the db - you could only get them by bruteforcing (which can really take a while; i.e. practically you can't).
Other than that:

1. send an email to the admin with the password upon each registration
2. an additional write to a table in another db
3. turn off md5 (what's it for anyway? O-)

Comment: You _really_ give advices to expose user passwords?!

Comment: it depends on where the system's used; if you're using it inside your network and for an office of 10 people - what the hell...; i had a case like that once, and people were always forgetting passwords and there was no "reset password" feature

Comment: Thats an absolutely No-No completely independent from wether it's just for internal, or public usage, or wether it's for 2 or 2 Billion users. If the developer forgot to implement "reset password" thats the fault of the developer and not of the users and especially it is not a reason to expose their password! Even when he users write their passwords on a piece of paper and put it in their wallet, it's much more secure than this...

Comment: 1. the question was "how" and not "should i" (i believe both points are well covered); 2. even with md5 - user passwords can be exposed; it is not your super seal that will everything much safer

Comment: 1. "how" is irrelevant in this case. It's like explaining a child on how to steal a car. 2.a) `md5` on it's own makes it at least _much_ more time consuming (and therefore unprofitable in most cases), but usually a developer b.I) would prefer at least `sha1` and b.II) would not just hash the _unsalted_ password. -- That something is "not safe enough" does _not_ mean, that one can, or even should omit it, because "so what?"