# How to output the password itself, not the password hash?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to output MD5 hashed password in plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126255/how-to-output-md5-hashed-password-in-plain-text)

I have a little problem, below is nmy code is a '$teacherpassword' variable where it contains the user's password with salt (random characters) around it.

```
$teacherpassword = md5(md5("g3f".$teacherpassword."rt4"));
```

Now lets say the passowrd is "Cricket", then if I echo `$teahcerpassword`, it does not output the word "Cricket", it outputs the password hash which is "1ac30ef9e714fff0ab12b398e379f358".

I want it to output the word "Cricket". How can I get it to output the password word itself and not the password hash?

Comment: You can't, md5 is a hash function. It is designed to only go in one direction. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: Are you talking about how to undo the call to `md5()`?

Comment: You even called the variable $teacherPassword? Your question looks like a student trying to reverse MD5 of teacher's passwords. If that is not the case still funny.

Comment: Once it is encrypted you can't get the password back, that's the whole point!

Comment: By commenting the line you've shown here, perhaps?

Comment: Hi, Ok maybe I have termed it wrong. My question is simply, how can I echo the password "Cricket", not echo "1ac30ef9e714fff0ab12b398e379f358"?

Comment: Look for your nearest rainbow table and grab some popcorn.

Answer (score 4):

The point of a hash is that it is one-way. It is different from an encryption, which is two-way.

You can not un-hash something.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: Here come da rep.  Gotta love these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible, a hash prevents that. A hashing algorithmus shorts a anyhow long input to a constant length output. it is not possible to make that backwards.

Inside a normal hashing algorithmus is the modulo operator used which reduces the information count. A information which was removed cannot be recovered. But it is possible to get the password back by using a so called rainbow table. But note that this is much more complex if a salt is used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify if the user entered the correct password... also hash the entered value and match both hashes ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Hashes are used instead of encrypted passwords to make it impossible for anyone else to get at someone's password, including a system administrator.  You can match the hash, but you cannot retrieve the original password from it.

That's a feature.  It makes for better security, since the only person who has access to the original password is the individual who created it.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are a one-way encryption. There is no way to get the password from the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary where you have some words and generated hashes, but the general notion of hashing is that it is computationally difficult to extract the original word

Answer (score 0):

Is it impossible to output the MD5 hash. MD5 is one way only. If you want the password, you have to set a new one. Or use 'John the ripper' to crack it...