# Entire range - Reverse MD5 lookup

Tags: encryption, md5

I am learning about encryption methods and I have a question about MD5.

I have seen there are several websites that have 'rainbow tables' that will give you reverse MD5 lookup, but, they can't lookup all the combinations possible.

For knowledge's sake, my question is this :

Hypothetically, if a group of people were to consider an upper limit (eg. 5 or 6 characters) and decide to map out the entire MD5 hash for all the values inside that range, storing the results in a database to use for reverse lookup. 
**1.** Do you think such a thing is probable.
 
**2.** If you can speculate, what kind of scale of resources would this mean?
**3.** To your knowledge have there been any public or private attempts to do this?

I am not referring to tables that have select entries based on a dictionary, but mapping the entire range upto a certain number of characters.

(I have refered to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes) question already.)

Comment: MD5 is officially broken, and SHA-1 is halfway there. Avoid them.

Comment: @Steven SHA-1 is far from broken. What they've done is reduce the number of attempts needed to find a collision from 2^80 to 2^51, which is still pretty darn good.

Comment: @NullUserException: Uhm, that is precisely the definition of "broken". If it takes *less* than brute force, it's broken.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Hmm, yes, it's broken. It's still *good enough* to detect *accidental* data corruption. I assume that the definition of "not broken too much" depends on your threat model.

Comment: @Piskvor: If I wanted to detect accidental corruption, I'd use something designed for this purpose and capable of making concrete guarantees, such as CRC-32.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Ah, good point :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5 or 6 characters is easy. 6 *bytes* is doable (that's 2<sup>48</sup> combinations), even with limited hardware.

Namely, a simple Core2 CPU from Intel will be able to hash one password in about 150 clock cycles (assuming you use a SSE2 implementation, which will hash four passwords in parallel in 600 clock cycles). With a 2.4 GHz quad core CPU (that's my PC, not exactly the newest machine available), I can then try about 2<sup>26</sup> passwords per second. For that kind of job, a massively parallel architecture is fine, hence it makes sense to use a GPU. For maybe 200$, you can buy a NVidia video card which will be about four times faster (i.e. 2<sup>28</sup> passwords per second). 6 alphanumeric characters (uppercase, lowercase and digits) are close to 2<sup>36</sup> combinations; trying them all is then a matter of 2<sup>(36-28)</sup> seconds, which is less than *five minutes*. With 6 random bytes, it will need 2<sup>20</sup> seconds, i.e. a bit less than a fortnight.

That's for the CPU cost. If you want to speed up the actual attack, you store the hash results: thus you will not need to recompute all those hashed passwords every time you attack a password (but you still have to do it once). 2<sup>36</sup> hash results (16 bytes each) mean 1 terabyte. You can buy a harddisk that big for 100$. 2<sup>48</sup> hash results imply 4096 times that storage space; in plain harddisks this will cost as much as a house: a bit expensive for the average bored student, but affordable for most kinds of governmental or criminal organizations.

Rainbow tables are an optimization trick for the storage. In rough terms, you store only one every *t* hash results, in exchange of having to do *t* lookups and *t<sup>2</sup>* hash computations for every attack. E.g., you choose *t=1000*, you only have to buy four harddisks instead of four thousands, but you will need to make 1000 lookups and a million hashes every time you want to crack a password (this will need a dozen seconds at most, if you do it right).

Hence you have two costs:

- The *CPU cost* is about computing hashes for the complete password space; with a table (rainbow or not) you have to do it once, and then can reuse that computational effort for every attacked password.
- The *storage cost* is about storing the hash results in order to easily attack several passwords. Harddisks are not very expensive, as shown above. Rainbow tables help you lower storage costs.

[Salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) defeats cost sharing through precomputed tables (whether they are rainbow tables or just plain tables has no effect here: tables are about reusing precomputed values for several attacked passwords, and salts prevent such recycling).

The CPU cost can be increased by defining that the hash procedure is not just a single hash computation; for instance, you can define the "password hash" as applying MD5 over the concatenation of 10000 copies of the password. This will make each attacker guess one
thousand times more expensive. It also makes legitimate password validation one thousands times more expensive, but most users will not mind (the user has just typed his password; he cannot really see whether the password verification took 10ms or 10µs).

Modern Unix-like systems (e.g. Linux) use "MD5" passwords which actually combine salting and iterated hashing, as described above. (Actually, a modern Linux system may use another hash function, such as SHA-256, but that does not change things much here.) So precomputed tables will not help, and the on-the-fly password cracking is expensive. A password with 6 alphanumeric characters can still be cracked within a few days, because 6 characters are kind of weak anyway. Also, many longer passwords are crackable because it turns out that human begins are bad are remembering passwords; hence they will not choose just any random sequence of characters, they will select passwords which have some "meaning". This reduces the space of possible passwords.

Answer (score 5):

1. It is possible.  For a small number of characters, it has already been done.  In the near future, it will be easy for larger numbers of characters.  MD5 isn't getting any stronger.
2. That's a function of time.  To reverse the entire 6-or-fewer-character alphanumeric space would require computing 62^6 entries.  That's 56 trillion MD5s.  That's doable by a determined small group or easy for a government, right now.  In the future, it will be doable on a home computer.  Remember, though, that as the number of allowable characters or the maximum length increases, the difficulty increase is exponential.
3. People already *have* done it.  But, honestly, it doesn't matter - because anyone with half an ounce of sense uses a random *salt*.  If you precompute the entire MD5 space and reverse it, that doesn't mean jack dandy if someone is using key strengthening or a good salt!  Read up on salting.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are any number of values that can map to a given hash. At best, we're determining the first in a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a rainbow table, and it's easily defeated with salting.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it is not only probable, but it's probably been done before.
2. It depends on whether they are mapping the entire possible range or just a range of ASCII characters. Let's say you need 128 bits + 6 bytes to store each match. That's 22 bytes. You'd need:

   - 6.32 GB to store all lowercase alphabetic combinations [a-z]
   - 405 GB to for all alphabetic combinations [a-zA-Z]
   - 1.13 TB for all alphanumeric combinations [a-zA-Z0-9]
   - 5.24 TB for all combinations that consists of letters, numbers and 18 symbols.

As you see, it increases exponentially, but even at 5.24 TB that's nothing to agencies like, say, the NSA or the CIA. They probably have done it.

As everyone else said, salting can easily defeat rainbow tables and that's almost as important as hashing. Read this: [Just hashing is far from enough - How to position against dictionary and rainbow attacks](http://www.kavoir.com/2010/03/just-hashing-is-far-from-enough-how-to-position-against-dictionary-and-rainbow-attacks.html)