# Getting MD5 codes from database and decoding it in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, md5

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [I Have md5 encrypted password, how to give the password to user when he uses “Forgot password”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428443/i-have-md5-encrypted-password-how-to-give-the-password-to-user-when-he-uses-for)
>   [PHP:How to send the original password to the user when he clicks forgot password which is encrypted by using md5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780198/phphow-to-send-the-original-password-to-the-user-when-he-clicks-forgot-password)

I do not know is it the right way to ask this question but I am implementing my own membership script in PHP and right now, I am stuck with the retrieving the MD5 codes from database. OK, I insert the user info to the database and because of the security issues I encrypted the password before saving it to database but my question is that when I try to create a forget your password stuff, how can I get the unencrypted password from the database. By the way I use MySQL and my question is not about inserting or retrieving data from database, I only ask how can I reverse the MD5 thing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't. You reset the password for *Forgot Password*.

Comment: *Encryption* is to *decryption* as *hash* is to… what? ;-)

Comment: hash is to ... comparing another hash i guess, thats the best i can come up with

Comment: @Ibrahim The point was that there is no *"dehash"*. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can't.** MD5 hashes, or *hashes* in general, are not reversible. That's exactly the reason why you're using them in the first place to store passwords, because *you do not want the responsibility of knowing the actual password*.

*Forgot password* functionality is implemented by sending an email to the user with a one-time link he has to click on and letting him enter a new password.

Comment: This is the best way of doing it. As a side note, you should salt your md5 hashes if the password is < 8 characters long because it is becoming easier to decode shorter md5 hashes.

Comment: @user You need to salt your passwords anyway, not just of they're short. Also, you shouldn't use MD5 anymore.

Comment: why do you mean by salt your passwords? and why should not i use MD5 anymore?

Comment: You can't.  Except when you can.  http://md5.gromweb.com/query/21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3

Comment: @Jay Read this excellent article @Tim linked to: http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html

Comment: @deceze that is very logical. thanks for your answer. but here I have another one. how can i make a unique one time link for each user to reset their password?

Comment: @Jay http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+generate+random+string+to+reset+password+%5Bphp%5D `do { /* generate random string */ } while (/* string exists in database */);` Then save it in a `password_reset_token` field or so for the user.

Comment: @Jay I met a hashed password the other day that was assaulted.

Comment: @deceze thanks a lot. @alex is it sarcasm?

Answer (score 2):

MD5 was intended to be one-way, but it's now thoroughly insecure.  If you're actually serious about having any measure of security, rather than just going through the motions, you have some reading to do:

http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html

[SHA512 vs. Blowfish and Bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561174/sha512-vs-blowfish-and-bcrypt/1561245#1561245)

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't get the password back ever again,

You hash the password entered and compare to the has in your database, thats how it works :) good luck

Comment: if they match, then you have the correct password. md5 is not reversible meaning it is a one way ticket, so even if someone get a hold of your hash it will be very difficult to kknow what is the password

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is a one-way hash so reversing it wont work.

How you do it is performa comparison against what is stored for example:
SQL for entering the user:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('$username', MD5('$password'));
```

This will mean that the password is stored as a hash.
When someone tries to log in you do the same thing but in a select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = MD5('$password');
```

If there's a result, then the user is authenticated, if there's more than 1 result, then you have fun :)

For the forgot password bit, you are better to set up a chain where the user's are emailed a code and a link. Where they can enter that code on the "password reset" page as well as a new password.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to deal with forgotten passwords, but figuring out the original password from an MD5 hash isn't really one of them.

For the record, however, you *really* shouldn't be using MD5 for this (or much of anything else related to security). MD5 is *pretty* badly broken -- unless there's *absolutely* no choice in the matter, switch to something else (oh, but you should also know that SHA-1 is only a little better than MD5).