# what are the php commands to create and retrieve password with SHA-256 encryption?

Tags: php, authentication, encryption, sha256

Newbie here. I'm trying to encrypt the user password using SHA-256 after they've made their account and then when the user tries to log in, it will try to match their input with any of the encrypted passwords in the mysql database. I was wondering if someone could give me an example code?

Comment: SHA-256 is not an encryption function but a hash function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashing works one-way, so you cannot really 'retrieve' what you have hashed.

When you save the password on registration, use something like this:

```
$hash=hash('sha256', $password);
```

And only save `$hash` in the database. When the user tries to log in, hash the password he tries to use and compare it to the one in the database (hashing will always give the same result for the same input). If they are the same, he can be logged in (if all additional checks are satisfied).

If you want to let the user recover his forgotten pass, refer to this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283490/password-recovery-how-to-decrypt-an-md5-encrypted-password/5283596#5283596).

Also, the best practice in hashing passwords is to use some kind of `salt`, which is out of the scope of this question, but please google it.

Comment: but _please_ "salt" the password first (i.e. concatenate a secret string) so that people with databases of SHA256 hashes can't look for matches.

Comment: what variable type do I associate with the hashed password in the mysql table?

Comment: @user701510 An SHA256 hash is always 64 characters long. That means your best bet would be a `CHAR(64)` (you don't need `VARCHAR`). [See also this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240973/php-when-using-a-sha256-hash-how-long-is-the-hash-ie-how-long-should-my-mys)

Answer (score 0):

If using PHP >= 5.5, you should be using `password_hash()` for storing passwords, and `password_verify()` to check. If using PHP >= 5.3, you should be using this [compatibility module](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). If using an earlier version of PHP, you should upgrade.

*Do not roll your own password hashing.* There is no stressing this enough. Take a look at [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) to see how fast passwords that have only been hashed with cryptographic hashes (that are designed to be fast!) can be cracked.