# How to decrypt the encrypted password in md5()?

Tags: mysql, hash, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

I have encrypt the password using the MySQL function md5(),

I need to decrypt the password,

Any one can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try all possible combinations :))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MD5() generates a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), not an [encrypted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) string. Thus you can't decrypt it *in principle*. But studies shown that MD5 is hackable, but it seems too complicated to study.
From "MD5 considered harmful today" @ http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/:

> The cryptographic operation that uses a private key to sign data does
>   not deal directly with the data itself, but with a purportedly unique
>   representation of this data, that has a predetermined fixed length, is
>   short and therefore convenient to work with. This can be compared to a
>   fingerprint as a purportedly unique, short and convenient
>   representation of a human being. The process of creating such short
>   representations of data is called "hashing". Unfortunately, because of
>   the fixed length of the hash, there must exist pairs of different
>   inputs that yield the same hash value. Good hash functions, however,
>   have the property that finding such pairs is extremely difficult, even
>   though they are guaranteed to exist. **This is precisely where MD5 has a
>   crucial weakness**.

Answer (score 6):

MD5 is not *encryption*, it is a *one-way hash*. This means that there is no way of going back to the original password given the hashvalue (other than brute-force or a rainbow table attack).

There is a longer, very good explanation, in [this similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes/1240869#1240869).

Answer (score 3):

In theory, MD5 cannot be decrypted.
In practice, there are many MD5 "decrypters", but they use brute force, or large database of already decrypted code etc... The answerer above probably used one of these. The number of possible combinations is a 1 followed by 48 zeros... enough for a life time.

Source: http://md5pass.com

Answer (score 2):

MD5 isn't an encryption algorithm.  It's a one-way hash algorithm, so without an attack, you're not supposed to be able to get the password from the MD5 hash.

The idea is that you generate a hash from the password, and then when provided with the password you can confirm that it hashes to the same value.  You're not supposed to be able to go the other way.

Answer (score 0):

The best reasonably simple way is to search the hash in Google. E.g.:

- http://www.google.es/search?q=73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc

Comment: And this will aid the OP in retrieving his password... how?

Comment: Because, as you would have found out if you had clicked on the link, MD5 hashes for most common passwords are already indexed in Google. E.g., `73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc` is the hash for `stackoverflow`.