#  How to get byte[] array back from md5 string

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

i have md5 checksum in string form.

example:

```
 string md5 = "83bb108c0c4d94fab1a6748ca1ddfba6";
```

i want to get the `byte[]` array back from this md5. i mean reverse `MD5CryptoServiceProvider.ComputHash()` method . is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to reverse the hash? If you are wanting to determine whether it is the hash of some data you have, then hash the data and compare the hashes.

Comment: i have open source antivirus database . this database is contains the md5 hashes of specific part of virus body . i want to figure out what the original bytes of the md5 hash to use it in virus detection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to understand that you want to obtain the original data from a given hash. That's not possible since a MD5 Hash inherently loses the original information in the digesting process.

You might want to check the [Hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) and the [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) wikipedia entries in order to better understand what a hash function is.