# How to store and manage password in database for use in scratch card?

Tags: php, scratchcard

I am developing a web application in which providing a scratch card with a user name and password. Storing password in database in unencrypted form is not secure.
But I want the passwords in plain text for scratchcard. I am thinking about the following options

1. Use decryptable algorithm for encription.
2. Store unencrypted passsword in another table.
3. Store the unencrypted password in local computer.

Which is the better option?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.

MD5 isn't supposed to be decrypt-able. Hash's are supposed to be one way functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

[Is md5 decryption possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396590/is-md5-decryption-possible)

Comment: I need a way to implement it, and not stick on decryption.