# How to decrypt the encrypted password using php?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

below is my encrypted code so, please tell how to decrypt the string using php.

```
<?php
$input = 'password';
$password_hash = md5($input);
echo "$password_hash";
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15194663/3282633

Answer (score 0):

[md5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a hashing technique. You cannot decrypt it back.Hashing means, once you are converted it to a encrypted code, you cannot go back! But you can still compare the md5 encrypted value with the another md5 encrypted value to check matches (mostly in the case of password verification and all!)

Copied from [Is md5 decryption possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396590/is-md5-decryption-possible)