# Will a website be able to decrypt a hashed password regardless of how it was hashed?

Tags: python, hash, md5

I'm creating a python script that logs into a website (in this case, it's the url to update your IPv4 endpoint for Tunnelbroker.net), and it uses a hashed username and password.

My question is this. If I use echo mypassword | md5sum it gives me a different hash than a python script that I found (using hashlib and hashdigest to accomplish the task).

For example, if "mypass" is robots, echo robots | md5sum gives me 2cf61812c352ec4fd0dae8f52874701d but if I run it through the python script, I get 27f5e15b6af3223f1176293cd015771d

- the script that I'm using is found at http://wiki.python.org/moin/Md5Passwords

My question is simply this: Will the website be able to decrypt either of those and get "robots"? I ask this, because I want to include a variation of the python script for hashing the password (in case the end user is on Windows or another operating system that can't generate a MD5 hash).

Thanks in advance, and have a great day:)
Patrick.

Comment: If you encrypt something, you can decrypt it, but if you hash something, that's irreversible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`md5` and passwords in the same sentence gives me chills..  `md5` is a type of one-way hash function, which mean there *should* be no way to ["decrypt"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes) once hashed. It is *not* an encryption function. However, with [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) (and possibly [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)), you *can* recover some common strings from  a `md5` hash, which makes the idea of using `md5` to encrypt password even worse.

But anyway, here is the answer:

No, the Python script's answer is the correct one. If you use `echo -n "robots" | md5sum` you will see they are the same: `27f5e15b6af3223f1176293cd015771d`

The reason is `echo` will append a newline character at the end of the string it's echoing (surprise!), adding `-n` will not print the newline char and hence give you the right result.

Alternatively, you can simply use `md5sum -s "robots"` or `md5 -s "robots"` to generate the hash without using `echo`.

---

Reference for `echo`:

> The echo utility writes any specified operands, separated
>   by single blank (`' '`) characters and followed by a newline (`\n`) character,
>   to the standard output.

[What password hashing algorithm to use?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/most-secure-password-hash-algorithms)

Answer (score 1):

the MD5 of the string "robots\n" is 2cf61812c352ec4fd0dae8f52874701d

the MD5 of the string "robots" is 27f5e15b6af3223f1176293cd015771d

What does `md5sum robots` give you?

Comment: I think you mean `md5sum "robots"`