# Decrypt The Md5 Encrypted Password?

Tags: md5

I am using md5 to encrypt the password. then, how to get back the original string if i need it. is there any decryption possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

Answer (score 3):

In a word: no. If you want it to be reversible, **this is the wrong approach.** MD5 is a *hashing* algorithm, not an encryption one. Don't use MD5 for passwords.

Use actual encryption, like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) or [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot decrypt one-way hashes like MD5 - The best you can do is brute-force them or run a dictionary through and compare the values for matches.

Comment: so, are you going to say that this [application](http://www.md5decrypt.org/) is some kind of brute force?

Comment: @HendryTanaka Sorry for taking long to answer but yes, you need to brute force them until you find a match or compare the value to an already-calculated mapping table (e.g. Rainbow tables)