# converting hexdigest string back to original string

Tags: python, python-2.7, md5

I have a string and I can create its md5 using hexdigest by doing this

```
import hashlib
ver = 'root123'
hashlib.md5(ver).hexdigest()
'ff9830c42660c1dd1942844f8069b74a'
```

Now I would like to reverse this process. I have a hexdigest string and I would like to convert it to its original string. Is their a python library or a function to do that

Thank you

Comment: It's not possible, it's the main feature of md5 :)

Comment: See [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1240852/222914)

Comment: Hash functions cannot compress data nor encrypt it. Information is lost during the process

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`md5` hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a [one way hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_hash). You *cannot get the original string back*. See more at:

- [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)