# How to fetch md5 password from database php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, md5

How to fetch md5 password from database.
i am making a login form>
i want,when the user is going to login.if the username and password text field is matched with database than use will login.

database..
in database,i store the password with md5().
now how to fetch the password from database.and how to make validation with this.
thanks all

```
<h1>Login Here</h1>
<form name="f1" action="login.php" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr><td>username</td><td><input type="text" name="t1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>password</td><td><input type="password" name="t2"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="login"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

login.php

```
  <?php
    include "db.php";
    $user=$_POST['t1'];
    $pass=$_POST['t2'];
    $result=mysql_query("select * from core where username='$user'")or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    ?>
    <h1>Welcome Mr. <?php echo $user;?></h1>
    <table border="1">
    <tr><td>Your User-Id :- </td><td><?php echo $row[0];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Your Username: </td><td><?php echo $row[1];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>your md5 Password: </td><td><?php echo $row[2];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>your Email Id: </td><td><?php echo $row[3];?></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Dont try to decode the password from database.Instead of that try encoding the user entered password as md5 and check it with that it the database.

Comment: What do you mean? Show us your current codes. Also, `md5()` is very unsafe for hashing password.

Comment: what have u tried so far? show us the code...

Comment: apply md5() function to the password string given while login and check to compare with that stored in the database.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this that I think my head is going to explode.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: just encode your password to md5 and after that compare it.

Comment: How to use validation ..if user going to login..I want to use validation.i mean ..how to compare database password(md5 form) with user entered password

Answer (score 0):

Dont try to decode the password from database and check it with that of user entered input pasword.Instead of that try encoding the user entered password as md5 and check it with that it the database.

> There is no way to decrypt MD5. Well, there is, but no reasonable way
>   to do it. That's kind of the point.

To check if someone is entering the correct password, you need to MD5 whatever the user entered, and see if it matches what you have in the database.
For more you can check in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes).

So what you can do is like this

```
 if(isset($_POST['t2']) && trim($_POST['t2']) != ''){
   $pass = md5(trim($_POST['t2']));
   //Do a select query for fetching with the username and $pass and do the rest
 }
```

Comment: *There is no way to decrypt MD5.* ? Can't agree with this. Although MD5 is an one-way hash algorithm, there are a lot of online resources that provides reverse mapping of md5 hashes (even `md5() * md5()` or combination of `md5() with sha1()` are reversed mapped).

Comment: You can find a well explained reason in the link in the answer. @ShivanRaptor