# JSON file with hashes decoding

Tags: python, json, r, hash

I have a JSON file that contains hashes and I don't know what what used to serialize it. Any solution in Python/R/Ruby/Java that could decode the hashes?

A sample of the file is,

```
browserWindowSize   {'width': '00409424d52c3a1a30e98cd1cd91638a', 'height': '58b6027d6f7d57e6f62e28fda6ccbb3b'}
```

and

```
dashboardview   {'id': '11daa4e390db3055eadebfdd80d0e8f8'}
```

any suggestions how to extract the information from this?

If it is of any help the complete file format is a mixture of tab separated file and JSON.

Comment: 1. The file is not JSON. 2. Cryptographic are also called " one way encryption" because they can not be reversed. The only way to get the cleartext is to bruteforce all possible values. That might be possible for numbers like height but the id could get complicated already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what kind of hashes this are i would say it is impossible.

If you know how the hash was created it is also not meant to be decrypted, as hashes are usually calculated with one way functions. decryption need rainbowtables or something like that.

Read this about md5 to get a clue: [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)