# Decryption or decoding or md5 base 64 in c#.net

Tags: unicode, base64, md5

Hi i created one function  for encryption using md5 an base 64

```
public string HashString(string s)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s)));
        }

        private MD5 Hash
        {
            get
            {
                return MD5.Create();

            }
        }
```

is it possible to decode to original string from the encrypted value because the i had done this for password and i want to decode the same for admin users

Comment: MD5 is not encryption. It's a one-way cryptographic hash function. And there's no way to "decrypt" a hash into the original value. See: [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes?rq=1)

Comment: MD5 is not encryption, and it is not reversible. So, no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)