# node.js MD5 decryption with crypto module

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I need to decrypt MD5 hashes in node.js (using crypto bultin module)
Didnt tried to do anything beacuse even didnt found anything about decryption MD5, not cipher.

```js
var hash = crypto.createHash("md5").update("example").digest("hex");
//how can i decrypt MD5 hash?
```

Comment: MD5 does not decrypt. MD5 is used to hide source and compare with destination encrypted too. Like md5(123456) = E10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E, then you transmit md5 from client to server to hide password from sniffers, and in server you get password 123456, apply md5 checksum = E10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E and compare with received Md5 if matches.

Comment: okay, edited before i said

Comment: Thanks for answer, i thought its possible to decrypt MD5

Comment: Once a string/file is encrypted as md5 you cannot decrypt. It's only a hash/calc from a source data. If you need to encrypt and decrypt data, try RSA or another with salt.

Comment: @cillian I suggest you google "what is the difference between an encryption algorithm and a hashing algorithm"

Comment: @Cilian Nope, you can only hash *not encrypt* nor decrypt; a hash is a *one-way* function. You can sometimes brute force all possible messages in a domain to try and find the same hash though.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer: **You can't.** Cryptographic hash functions are one-way functions. Some people call them "one-way encryption" but hash functions like MD5 aren't encryption at all. They're cryptographic, but [not all cryptography is encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240869/2224584).