# Hash de-encryption type MD5

Tags: url, hash, python-requests, byte, md5

This is hash type MD5 '9931BF135E464FE91E444DF4E046006A' but I can't change it to string is there any website that can do that.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the original text from which that MD5 hash was created?

Comment: Yes I want the main string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to decrypt MD5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why what you're asking is not possible.

First, the process by which the MD5 hash code is created loses information. MD5 is a 128-bit hash code. So if you take the hash code of anything larger than 128 bits (that's 16 bytes), by definition you're going to lose information.

Related: there is an infinite number of possible strings. By the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there is more than one string that will hash to any particular MD5 value.