# Is the algorithm exist:appending md5 string to an string, the appended string's md5 is just the inserted string

Tags: algorithm, md5sum

I want to find a md5 string which meet the result.
After append the md5 with a known string.
For example:
Given string: "abcde"
find a md5 string(md5_str). Suppose it is:"XXXXX"

Appended string is:
"abcdeXXXXX".
And its md5 is just md5_str.

```
md5(abcdeXXXXX) = XXXXX
```

Comment: for many strings such an MD5 will not exist and if it does it is not easy to find.

Comment: it sounds like this algorithm may not exist for many string.

Comment: Algorithms exist, it is just not sure they will find a solution or run in a reasonable time. For example, you can run through all possible MD5 sums and check for each if it works.

Comment: See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes . That being said, md5 is considered "weak", and googling "break md5" does yield interesting results.

Comment: I check the link：“https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes”。 It builds a database to find the results. But this is a very big task.