# Is there a secure way to store passwords for a website?

Tags: python, flask, cryptography

I am developing a social networking site and I have implemented basic functionalities like signup and login. I have used Basic HTML/CSS/JS for front end and Python (Flask) in the backend with Firebase DB. The problem is , I am able to access the database and I can see the password of all the registered users. Is there a secure way by which passwords can be stored so that Admins (Me) cannot misuse it?

Comment: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/password-hashing-pbkdf2-scrypt-bcrypt-and-argon2-e25aaf41598e : basically you add a `salt` (a short random string to the password), run a hash function several thousand times over `salt + password`, store the `salt`and the hash result. there are standard ways to to this:  PBKDF2, Scrypt, Bcrypt, argon2, ...

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/argon2-cffi/ or https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-bcrypt or many others.,.

Comment: Securing passwords is hard. Consider using [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) instead.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I generate a salt to the password and I run a hash function several times. After doing this, I store the salt and hashed password in my database. Now I have access to both the salt and hash value. So won't I be able to decrypt the same data?

Comment: hash functions are **one-way** - they are designed such that it is computationally infeasible to go back (i.e. the best attack should be that you try to brute-force the input). repeating the hashing slows down this attack. hashing is not the same as encryption (where you want to be able to undo the operation).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Thanks! I am relatively new to cryptography and cybersecurity . So I got confused between hashing algorithms and encryption algorithms.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I'd recommend passlib as a clearing house of secrets management, it's well documented, has excellent guides, has a rather good API, and has built-in support for upgrading hashing schemes online (though I don't think it has double-hashing support sadly)

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/86735

Comment: @hiroprotagonist the actual boundry not exact. Actually, a hash function can be used for encryption. The CTR mode actually designed for PRF and we use it with PRP in AES-CTR and with FRF with ChaCha20. That is [long story](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64451775/1820553) or see here [the long message distinguisher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/85572/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka yep. sure. but then you do not use the plaintext as input to the hash funciton - which is the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

werkzeug takes care of this for you. Basically, the passwords are stored in their hashed form so all you'll see is a big bunch of random characters. In your models.py file add:

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
```

then wherever you set up your users table you set the password as "generate_password_hash". There's a more detailed example [here](https://techmonger.github.io/4/secure-passwords-werkzeug/).