# Get Object From Hash

Tags: python-3.x

As per my understanding for each hash able object there is unique hash value for each object and we can get hash value from `hash` function .

Below is the example:

```
>>> f="hello_world"
>>> hash(f)
6743345533036935742
>>> hash("hello_world")
6743345533036935742
>>>
```

Now I want to get the object back from hash value.

**Update:**

**Q. Why I want this ?**

I am deserializing  a huge number of objects from file and appending it to a list.

Here I am returning id of the attribute `unique_serial_number` ,having data type is string, of each object as an hash value.

Below is my code.

```
class CustomObject:
    def __init__(self,unique_serial_number,name):
        self.unique_serial_number = unique_serial_number
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, CustomObject):
            return self.unique_serial_number==other.unique_serial_number
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self.unique_serial_number)
```

I have list of strings of unique_serial_number , and since I can get the id of serialnumber and hence I was assuming to get object from these id and will modify other attribue without going through entire list of object and checking `unique_serial_number` attribute of each object.

However, I got to know that it is not possible from the comments But I want to give the context

Comment: You can not. It's a one way function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to decrypt MD5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

Comment: Moreover, multiple values can have identical hashes, a hash is not unique.

Comment: What's the actual context here, why is this desirable? What should happen in the case of collisions? Why not just use some kind of mapping?

Comment: Can someone suggest me a better alternative to achieve my motive

Comment: I'm not following exactly what you are attempting to do, but my intuition tells me you might be looking for a `dict()` to store objects based on some key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to get the object back from hash value.

It's not a bidirectional method, so you cannot do this safely.

In Python, the `hash()` function is primarily used to generate a hash value for a given object. It's important to note that **the hash value is not guaranteed to be unique for every object**, and it's possible for different objects to have the same hash value (this is called a hash collision). Additionally, the `hash()` function is not intended for reverse lookup; that is, you cannot retrieve the original object from its hash value using built-in Python functions